# How to acess the variables of type Optional<Some_Type> in java?

Tags: java

I have a one Student class inside my main class. Student class contains an Id and name. In my main class, I am adding the 3 students to the list. Now I need to fetch the first student whose name shouldn't be null. For this, I have used the java stream() class wherein it contains **findFirst()** method to get the first matching value. So the return type is **Optional**.

This is what I wrote

```
Optional<Student> ans = l.stream()
                        .filter(e -> e != null && e.name != null)
                        .findFirst();
```

I can also write like this

```
Student ans = l.stream()
               .filter(e -> e != null && e.name != null)
               .findFirst()
               .orElse(null);
```

But I don't want to have **orElse(null)**

My Entire Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Sample {

public static class Student { 
    int id;
    String name;
}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Student> l = new ArrayList<>();
        Student s = new Student();
        s.id = 0;
        s.name  = "First";

        Student t = new Student();
        t.id = 1;
        t.name = "";

        Student r = new Student();
        r.id = 2;
        r.name = "Hdyun";

        l.add(s);
        l.add(t);
        l.add(r);

        Optional<Student> ans = l.stream()
                        .filter(e -> e != null && e.name != null)
                        .findFirst();
        System.out.println(ans.name);
    }
}
```

At last, when I am printing the name, I facing the following error:

```
Sample.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(ans.name);
                              ^
  symbol:   variable name
  location: variable ans of type Optional<Student>
```

How can I rectify it?

Comment: Have you considered [taking a look at the documentation of Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#get())? What methods a class have and how it is used is usually well defined and explained in some official documents.

Comment: What would you want `ans.name` to do if the result is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable ans may be empty; if you want to execute some action if the value is present you can do something like:

```
ans.ifPresent(student-> System.out.println(student.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

The main sense of `Optional` is forced handling of nullable values.
It means that all elements in collection may not match your condition so when you call `findFirst()` it may returns empty Optional.

In your case you can use `.ifPresent(...)` or `orElseThrow` if you are sure that collection always contains necessary element.